# How do I ping localhost using IPv6?

Tags: linux, networking, ping, ipv6, localhost

I'm trying to understand [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) better.

Firstly, I try [ifconfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig), and I get the following:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XXXXXXX
          inet addr:X.X.X.X  Bcast:X.X.X.X  Mask:XXXXXXXXX
          inet6 addr: XXXX::XXXX:XXX:XXXX:XXX/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:138752772 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:67894054 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:67347428211 (67.3 GB)  TX bytes:168368922639 (168.3 GB)
          Interrupt:43
```

So from the above I can assume IPv6 is enabled (correct me if I'm wrong here).

Now if I use `ping localhost` I get:

```
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.026 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.019 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.025 ms
...
```

But when I use `ping6 localhost` I get:

```
unknown host
```

How do I use `ping6`? Or more specifically, what changes needs to be done to make `ping6 localhost` work (if possible at all)?

Comment: If you're on Linux, you should generally avoid `ifconfig` and `route` – prefer `ip addr` and `ip route`, which support more networking features and have a more consistent output.

Comment: @grawity thx for the tip mate, very useful

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Short answer <sup>[[rcf4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.3)]</sup>**

```
ping6 ip6-localhost    # Or the alias you have in /etc/hosts file (See below)
ping6 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1  # Similar to `ping 127.0.0.1` with 7 `:` instead of 4 `.`
ping6 ::1              # The used analogous of `ping 127.0.0.1`
```

**Changes to make working `ping6 localhost`**

If you **want to set `localhost` as alias for both `ping` and `ping6`** and it is not already so on your machine, it is enough to write in `/etc/hosts` file both the lines:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
# ... and below
::1             localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback
```

For what it concerns the **alias currently used** on your system you can check your hosts file, `/etc/hosts` <sup>[[1](http://linux.about.com/od/lna_guide/a/gdelna46.htm)]</sup>   or in a different *place* if on a different system  <sup>[[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)]</sup> .
<sub>You may find `ip6-localhost`,`ip6-loopback`,`ipv6-localhost`,`ipv6-loopback` or `localhost` itself...</sub>

---

**Some words more**

I understand your confusion indeed for what I read from the ***rfc6761*** about *"Special-Use Domain Names"* 6.3 <sup>[[3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6761)]</sup>, about the name *localhost*,

> Users may assume that IPv4 and IPv6 address queries for **localhost names will always resolve to the respective IP loopback address**.

so **it should be expected as default**  but:

- On the current updated and untouched **Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS** `/etc/hosts` I found the following section with `ip6-localhost`, `ip6-loopback`

  ```
   # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
   ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
   fe00::0 ip6-localnet
   ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
   ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
   ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
  ```
- On a **Suse Enterprise 10** system I found `localhost`, `ipv6-localhost`,`ipv6-loopback`

  ```
   # special IPv6 addresses
   ::1             localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback
  ```
- On an old  **Debian GNU/Linux 8.2**  system `localhost`, `ip6-localhost`, `ip6-loopback`

  ```
   # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
   ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
  ```

That means that, in my limited experience, you should look in your `/etc/host` file and modify it or use what will you find doing, for example,

```
ping6 ipv6-localhost   # On some systems (maybe on Suse) 
ping6 ip6-localhost    # On some systems (maybe on Debian/*buntu)
```

Comment: very detailed answer thanks, what worries me atm, we will be required to use ipv6 very soon and yet, there are so much obstacle ( it couldn't get any simpler than localhost really) and there is no standarizations. I guess we won't do anything about it until, it causes soo much troubles...

Comment: As you have seen `::1` works on each of those machines... _"The nice thing about standards is that you have so many to choose from." A.S.Tanenbaum [ [1](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Andrew_S._Tanenbaum)]_ :-)  A solution  will be found... maybe the wrong one! ;)

Comment: ,I totally get it mate. `::1` is the ip(v6), where as `localhost` is the `hostname`. entirely my opinion but I believe if we don't keep the standard as are, we'll face many issues in near future. I really hope that once ipv6 overtakes we don't have to type e.g. `ipv6.google.com` instead of `google.com`

Comment: It was clear that you get it :-) ... BTW [RFC 6761 (Special-Use Domain Names) achieved the Proposed Standard maturity level in February, 2013.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost#IETF_standards)... so there is still time to hope to see it as standard before it will be too late.

Comment: @nafas They have added IPv6 to `google.com`.

Comment: @nafas `google.com` has had an IPv6 address since 2012-06-06.

Answer (score 25):

Try:

```
ping6 ::1
```

The result would look like:

```
# ping6 ::1
PING ::1(::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.040 ms
(...)
64 bytes from ::1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=0.037 ms
^C
--- ::1 ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 9 received, 0% packet loss, time 7998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.035/0.042/0.055/0.011 ms
```

Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (Trusty Tahr):

```
# ping ::1
ping: unknown host ::1
# ping -6 ::1
ping: invalid option -- '6'
Usage: ping [-aAbBdDfhLnOqrRUvV] [-c count] [-i interval] [-I interface]
        [-m mark] [-M pmtudisc_option] [-l preload] [-p pattern] [-Q tos]
        [-s packetsize] [-S sndbuf] [-t ttl] [-T timestamp_option]
        [-w deadline] [-W timeout] [hop1 ...] destination
# ping -V
ping utility, iputils-s20121221
```

(The same for `ping6 -V`.)

Comment: Newer versions of `iputils` have no separate `ping6` utility, it got merged with `ping`. For those versions, use `ping -6 ::1` or (since `::1` is not an IPv4 address) `ping ::1`.

Comment: @Lekensteyn Which? Latest version, `-6` is not even recognized.

Comment: @black: Which version do you consider "latest"? ping and ping6 were merged in iputils-s20150815 (check `ping -V`). Your distro might not have upgraded yet. (And BSDs have their own software and don't use iputils.)

Comment: @grawity: I do have the latest version, though it's not the actual latest version and it's indeed OOD, even on Arch Linux (20140519).

Comment: @black: "Latest but not the actual latest"?... Anyway, Arch has had iputils-20150815 in [testing] for over a month, although I've no idea when it's going to be moved to stable.

Comment: @grawity It is indeed the latest you can get from [core] (because it's OOD), but the actual latest version is only in [testing].

Comment: Newest Ubuntu LTS has iputils-s20121221, which does not support `ping -6`.

Comment: @black This was iputils 20150815.1c59920-3 on Arch Linux

Answer (score 9):

`localhost` is the hostname that resolves to the `127.0.0.1` address. Your `/etc/hosts` file should have a separate entry for `::1`, likely `localhost6`. So try these:

```
ping6 ::1
ping6 localhost6
```

Comment: A hostname can resolve to multiple addresses at once – especially if they're from different protocols. Most systems alias `localhost` to **both** `127.0.0.1` and `::1`.

Comment: @grawity None of the systems I checked use `localhost` for IPv6. The names I found used for `::1` were `ip6-localhost`, `ip6-loopback`, `localhost6`, and `localhost6.localdomain6`.

Comment: @kasperd, from a Gentoo `/etc/hosts`: `127.0.0.1 localhost`, `::1  localhost`; Windows Vista is identical (except for putting the file in `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`).  MacOSX 10.9.5 adds `fe80::1%lo0 localhost` as a third name for it.

Comment: @kasperd: You haven't used many systems then. Windows, Arch, CentOS, Ubuntu all map `localhost` to `::1`. (I think this is going to be even more common as distros adopt systemd and enable nss_myhostname.)

Comment: @grawity That's not correct. In `/etc/hosts` on Ubuntu I find this: `::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback`

Comment: @kasperd: [Really.](http://i.imgur.com/y2XQOah.png)

Comment: @grawity That information is outdated. I found some older media with Ubuntu 9.10 and 10.04. Those versions have `::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback`, but on 12.04 and 14.04 it says `::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback`.

Comment: CentOS 6 has ::1 as localhost6, though CentOS 7 has localhost for both. OpenWRT, Xenserver, and Solaris lack any IPv6 entries at all.