# Ubuntu IPv6 ping self gives unknown host

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, localhost

I'm stuck trying to get IPv6 working on a new Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) install. My scenario is very basic - trying to ping the local IPv6 address.

```
$ ifconfig
enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:ae:ed:77:91:fa
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e/64 Scope:Link
```

and

```
$ ping6 -c 5 -I enp0s25 fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e/64
```

results in

```
unknown host
```

How do I troubleshoot?

Comment: Bonk... I had tried that and got invalid argument, but, at that time I didn't specify -I also. Thanks!

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1005335/how-do-i-ping-localhost-using-ipv6

Comment: FYI: `ifconfig` is deprecated. You want to use `ip address` or `ip a` instead.

Answer (score 10):

Works with /64 removed and -I specified. The /64 refers to the number of bits in the mask and shouldn't be used in ping.

```
$ ping6 -c 1 -I enp0s25 fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e
PING fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e(fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e) from fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e enp0s25: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.043 ms
```

The local interface argument -I can be specified in the address instead by appending `%` and the interface name:

```
$ ping6 fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e%enp0s25
PING fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e%enp0s25(fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms
64 bytes from fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.059 ms
...
```

These combinations don't work:

```
$ ping6 -c 1 -I enp0s25 fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e/64
unknown host
```

or

```
$ ping6 fe80::ba94:3d5e:9929:4c6e
connect: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Is that an answer or a follow-up? [This site is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115). It is a [think tank](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325681).

Comment: @PeterMortensen it’s a valid answer, to Ping a link local network address you must specify the interface and to use a ip6 address with pink you must not specify a / suffix.

Comment: @PeterMortensen This is a perfectly valid answer to the question. In fact it is even a better answer than the one posted later. This answer gives examples of valid syntax and points out that there are two different ways to specify the interface.

Answer (score 8):

You should not use the `/64` on the address in the ping. That would be the equivalent of using a mask length or mask on the ping command for IPv4. I suppose the ping command was trying to interpret that as a host name.